# Use multiple WITH tablename AS (…) statements using Postgres version 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, postgresql-9.3

There is an exact question like this for SQL server but I'm using Postgres 9.3 and the `','` didn't work

I am making a comparison between 2 separate years. e.g. 2016 and 2015

I check the user if he received any bad grades with same subjects over a course of 2 years.

My code goes as follows

```
with currentyeargrade ( 
      select ....
      from (...
             ...)t)

with previousyeargrade(
      select ....
      from (...
             ...)y)

select *
from currentyeargrade cyg
inner join previousyeargrade pvg on pvg.userid = cyg.userid
```

I am an SQL developer and I do not have admin privileges to create a temp table.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) you only need to write `with` in the first `CTE` and use `,` comma to connect multiple `CTE`.

```
with currentyeargrade as ( 
      select ....
      from (...
             ...)t),
previousyeargrade as(
      select ....
      from (...
             ...)y)
select *
from currentyeargrade cyg
inner join previousyeargrade pvg on pvg.userid = cyg.userid
```

Here is a sample for you

```
CREATE TABLE T(col int);

insert into T values (1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
with currentyeargrade as  (SELECT * FROM T), 
previousyeargrade as (SELECT * FROM T)
select *
from previousyeargrade cyg
CROSS JOIN currentyeargrade pvg
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6bd4e/4/0)**:

```
| col | col |
|-----|-----|
|   1 |   1 |
```

Comment: the difference was you removed the with on the second line, trying that now!

Comment: Awesome. Perfect Answer! Slight difference between SQL Server but removing the with worked! Thanks

Comment: @Tito No problem glad to help